# How to find files in Linux using "locate"?

Tags: linux, locate

I would like to use this command to find some files.

Comment: Which shell are you using? `bash`, `tcsh`, ??

Comment: This is getting ridiculous; you just read the man page

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's simply

```
locate some_file
```

If you are going to use wildcards you must enclose the name in quotes. E.g. to find all `.jpg` files:

```
locate "*.jpg"
```

(@UlrichDangel was kind enough to clear this up for me)

For more information consult the [locate man page](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?locate+1).

Comment: if you are using `locate *.jpg` in bash - bash will try to expand *.jpg before executing locate. If you have files matching your parameter locate will get the matched filenames and not `*.jpg`. You should always quote, even with bash.

Comment: No. If you have a file named `1.jpg` in your current directory and run `locate *.jpg` (without quoting) the executed command will be `locate 1.jpg` so it will look for all files named `1.jpg`. But the implementation of locate may do something special if you specify an existing file. BUT the takeaway is you also have to quote with bash. We should chat if you have any more questions

Comment: @UlrichDangel Never mind .. I got it! Your last comment using `1.jpg` was very clear .. never thought about the shell expanding this in that way. Thanks again!

Comment: there is also mlocate .. etc http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locate_(Unix)